# showandwait changing variable value

Tags: variables, nested, javafx-2

I'm having a problem with a variable I'm using to track the status of a user activity. In a GUI I have a button that, on clicking the button launches a second GUI. In that GUI, the user can either complete the activity started in the first GUI or not.

If the user cancels the second GUI, then the idea is to go back to the first GUI, leaving all variables and lists with their current values. If the second GUI completes the activity of the first GUI, then all variables and lists should be reset.

To track this, I have a variable (Boolean complete) initially set to FALSE. In the second GUI, when the "OK" button is clicked (rather than the "Cancel" button), the second GUI calls a method in the first GUI, changing the value of "complete" to TRUE.

To see what the heck is going on, I have System.out.println at several points allowing me to see the value of "complete" along the way. What I see is this:

```
Launching first GUI - complete = FALSE
Launching second GUI - complete = FALSE
Clicking "OK" in second GUI - complete = TRUE
Second GUI closes itself, returning to complete first GUI activity
First GUI finishes activity with complete = FALSE
```

I'm assuming it is because I am launching the second GUI with a showandwait, and when the method containing the showandwait begins, the value of "complete" = FALSE. The value changes in the WAIT part of show and wait, then the method continues and that is where I get the value still being FALSE, though it was changed to TRUE.

Here is a summary of the code in question (if you need exact code, it's longer, but I can post on request):

```
    completeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            try {
                System.out.println("b4 calc = " + complete); // complete = FALSE

                // all the code to create the calcStage
                calcStage.showAndWait(); // second GUI, which calls a method in THIS
                      // class that changes complete to TRUE. That method 
                      // (in THIS file) also has a println that shows the change.

                getComplete(); // tried adding this method to check the value of
                               // "complete" after the change made by the calcStage
                               // (which calls a method in this same file)

                System.out.println("Complete? " + complete); 
                               // this shows complete = FALSE, 
                               // though in the calcStage it was changed to TRUE

                if (salecomplete) {
//       code that should reset all variables and lists if the activity was completed
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The question here is why does the second GUI successfully change the value of "complete", but when I return to the first GUI it still sees complete as FALSE? And how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try having the controller of the second GUI calling a method in the first GUI's controller to modify that complete variable

For example:

```
// Code to handle the OK button being pressed

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
    // Do validation and work

   //reference to the first controller object
   firstController.setComplete(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried that. For some reason, though the method (in the 1st GUI) called from the 2nd GUI reports the value of complete being successfully changed to TRUE, when the second GUI closes and the 1st GUI resumes the method which called the 2nd GUI, the value is once again reported as FALSE. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: Are you actually setting the instance variable in the first controller when that method is called?